# Unity EventTrigger steals OnDrop but not OnDrag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written my own component in Unity, which implements IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler and IDropHandler. I want to add an EventTrigger component that comes with UnityEngine.UI, but when I add it I stop getting calls to OnDrop on my component. OnBeginDrag and OnDrag are called as usual.

My component code:

```
public class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IDropHandler
{
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnBeginDrag!");
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDrag!");
    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDrop!");
    }
}
```

When I start my scene with a Game object with this component attached, the expected log output is:

```
OnBeginDrag!
OnDrag!
...
OnDrag!
OnDrop!
```

This is the case as long as I only have default components and my component. But if I add an Event -> Event Trigger component (without even specifying anything in it) to the same GameObject and run again, the output is:

```
OnBeginDrag!
OnDrag!
...
OnDrag!
```

The OnDrop is never called. The order of the components doesn't affect anything.

Is there a way to stop EventTrigger from using up the OnDrop call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this has been here for a long time (I can't remember when I found it too but at least 1.5-2 years ago)...

A workaround is to use `OnEndDrag` event as it's always called (without an **EventTrigger** component it get called right after `OnDrop`). Also it makes sens that both those events symbolize quite the same thing: an item won't be dropped if it hasn't started being dragged beforehand.

Otherwise you could "copy" the **EventTrigger** class behaviour in your own script with the possibility of assigning a *GameObject* and a *Method* (and even *Parameters*) that will be called when `OnDrop` is called so you won't have to add an **EventTrigger** component.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Using EndDrag instead indeed solved the problem, thank you! Do you know if the Unity dev team has been notified about this?

Comment: @Helena Not 100% sure but I guess I saw a thread on the Unity forums where a dev answered about this so I think they're aware of this. Not sure however if a bug report has been filled already.